# Trying to find Warren D. Smith's Matrix Multiplication article

Tags: matrix-product

One of my favorite articles on the complexity of matrix multiplication has gone dark.

Warren Smith, Fast Matrix Algorithms And Multiplication Formulae,  https://math.cst.temple.edu/~wds/matgrant.ps

I especially liked the explanation of Brent equations.

Does anyone have a copy?

Comment: Have you tried emailing the author?  Email address can be found here: http://rangevoting.org/voldir/Directory.html